# dataframe groupby nth with same behaviour as first and last

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

In a dataframe, when performing groupby['col'].first() we get the first not nan value in each column (same for last).
I am trying to get the second not nan value and I cannot find how.  The only relevant function that I found is groupby['col'].nth(1), but it just gives me the second row with nans if exist.  groupby['col'].nth(1, dropna='any') doesn't do the job since it skips rows with nans and doesn't check each column seperately.
example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'B': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5]
}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

first() behaviour:
`df.groupby('A').first().reset_index()`

results with:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2.0 3.0
```

on the other hand:
df.groupby('A').nth(0, dropna='any').reset_index()
gives:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   3.0 3.0
```

Is there a way to get the same behaviour of first/last in the nth function so I can apply it also for second or any nth item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic `aggregate` method to filter each series with `notna` and then pick the index you want, for example:

```
df.groupby('A').aggregate(lambda x: x.array[pd.notna(x)][0])
```

Produces:

```
     B    C
A
1  2.0  3.0
```

Changing the index to 1 to get the second `notna` value gives:

```
     B    C
A
1  3.0  4.0
```

Of course that lambda is a bit naive because it will raise an `IndexError` if the array isn't long enough. A function like this should work:

```
def nth_notna(n):
    def inner(series):
        a = series.array[pd.notna(series)]
        if len(a) - 1 < n:
            return np.nan
        return a[n]
    
    return inner
```

Then `df.groupby('A').aggregate(nth_notna(3))` will produce:

```
     B   C
A
1  5.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer made me realize that I didn't ask my question properly.  I edited it now with an example.

Comment: Thanks that's much clearer. I've updated my answer, hope it helps.